# How to replace multiple occurrence with each unique value using preg_replace in php

Tags: php, regex

I have some words in a paragraph and I want to replace all with different values using PHP preg_replace() function and I solving with following code snippet but not able to solve that one.

```
$str = "abc abc abc abc abc abc";
$strArr = ["xyz", "pqr", "mnl", "01j", "pqr", "lmn"];

$count = preg_match_all("/abc/is", $str, $matches);
for($i = 0; $i < $count; $i++) {
    preg_replace('/abc"([^\\"]+)"/', $strArr[$i], $str);
}
// At the end I need to get like as following
$str = "xyz pqr mnl 01j pqr lmn";
```

It is replacing only one first occurrence.

Comment: your code work fine, i got "xyz pqr mnl 01j pqr lmn"

Comment: You Check this not getting    https://paiza.io/projects/v4XzHpVSHGGQoxAcxjkJAA

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do it with `preg_replace_callback`:

```
$str = "abc abc abc abc abc abc";
$strArr = ["xyz", "pqr", "mnl", "01j", "pqr", "lmn"];

$count = 0;
echo preg_replace_callback(
    '/abc/',
    function ($v) use ($strArr, &$count) {
        return $strArr[$count++];
    },
    $str
);
```

Or even without counter:

```
echo preg_replace_callback(
    '/abc/',
    function ($v) use (&$strArr) {
        return array_shift($strArr);
    },
    $str
);
```